# Unified title and toolbar in swift with storyboards without title visibilty

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, xcode6

I want unified title toolbar like in calendar app without title.
I have tried following-
in viewDidLoad I added-

```
self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .Hidden
```

I have selected unified title and toolbar in attribute inspector.

I also tried adding titleVisibility to 1 in user defined runtime attributes in identity inspector.

I am not able to achieve unified title with toolbar without title. What am I missing. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select your Window in storyboard and check `Unified Title And Toolbar`-box. That should do it with your `.Hidden` in subclass of `NSWindowController`.

Comment: Select your Window in storyboard and check Unified Title And Toolbar-box>>it is done. but how to do ""That should do it with your .Hidden in subclass of NSWindowController""

Comment: You need put that `self.window?.titleVisibility = .Hidden` to subclass of `NSWindowController's` windowDidLoad -method

Comment: Make new file -> Source, Cocoa Class -> Select subclass of `NSWindowController` and then in your storyboard click your window and that blue icon on top which say Window Controller and set it's class to class that you just made.

Comment: Thanks for help. Sorry if I was annoying. I am new to this mac OS X development.